# ImageView in self-sizing table cell uses height of image before Aspect Fit is applied

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have an ImageView inside of a self-sizing table cell that has a content mode of Aspect Fit.
When the table fully loads the image itself looks great, it resizes to fit within the width of the cell while still keeping the original ratio.
However, the height of the table cell is as large as if the Aspect Fit content mode was never applied to the image view.

[image]

The red in this image is the image view and the space above and below the actual image is what I'm trying to avoid.

When I replace Aspect Fit with Aspect Fill, this is what the same cell looks like:

[image]

This is what I mean when I say it looks like the image view is using the height of the image before Aspect Fit is applied.

Am I missing a constraint or setting in the ImageView?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you set a constraint for the height of your image view within your cell?

Comment: where are these images coming from? Are they being downloaded from a remote server or are they in your assets.xcassets file?

Comment: The images are being a downloaded from a URL.

Comment: I have not set a constraint for height because I want the cell to resize depending on the size of the image. I feel like adding a constraint would create a fixed-height image which I’m trying to avoid

Comment: if you provide more code on how you are setting your tableview and downloading images, then I can help in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are being downloaded from a server, they will take a second or a millisecond to be downloaded. The time they take to download is noticeable to the user. The best user experience is explicitly setting the height and width before the image is downloaded. If you are using a third party API to fetch the image (i.e. facebook or youtube API), the return will include the image URL along with the height and width for the image. This way you can set the height and width of the cell and then wait for the image to download without any interruption or change in the size of cells. This would be the best way to do it. By having the height and width set explicitly, you don't need to worry as much about the content mode to use for the image view. I would only recommend using a self sizing UITableViewCell if you are explicitly setting the height and width of image view within that cell. I hope this helps!

I just saw your most recent comment. You can adjust the size of each image view within each cell depending on the image that is being returned. You don't need to set a fixed height for the image view. You can change the height of each cell depending on the image that is in that cell. I would just recommend doing this before the image is downloaded.

If you are using storyboard, then one way to do this is creating an outlet for the height constraint of the image view.